# How can I make a tag cloud with popularity-based opacity?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I really like this design for a tags page:
[image]

I found it on this site: https://www.webfx.com/blog/web-design/navigation-design-patterns/

How can I recreate it exactly? HTML, CSS would be really helpful as I am a beginner to web dev.

I suspect I will need some JS to find the most popular tag and normalize everything else from 0 to 1 using that?

Edit:

I found the original site:
https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com/explore/images/

Copying the HTML and CSS gives me this:
[image]

But they're all the same colour because I just copied the styling of one of them, so I think need JS.

CSS:

```
ul, ol {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul.image-tags li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.image-tags li a:hover, ul.image-tags li a.filtered, ul.image-tags li form {
    background: #f7421b;
    opacity: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
}

ul.image-tags li a:link, ul.image-tags li a:visited, ul.image-tags li form {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 0 5px 10px 0;
    background: #2b2b33;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="section tags">
  <ul class="image-tags">
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/app/" class="tag-size-4" title="View all images tagged with App (2110)">App&nbsp;(2110)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/apple/" class="tag-size-4" title="View all images tagged with Apple (2098)">Apple&nbsp;(2098)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/black/" class="tag-size-2" title="View all images tagged with Black (1417)">Black&nbsp;(1417)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/blog/" class="tag-size-4" title="View all images tagged with Blog (2281)">Blog&nbsp;(2281)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/blue/" class="tag-size-3" title="View all images tagged with Blue (1964)">Blue&nbsp;(1964)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/clean/" class="tag-size-5" title="View all images tagged with Clean (2566)">Clean&nbsp;(2566)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/color/" class="tag-size-4" title="View all images tagged with Color (2246)">Color&nbsp;(2246)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/dark/" class="tag-size-4" title="View all images tagged with Dark (2122)">Dark&nbsp;(2122)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/design/" class="tag-size-12" title="View all images tagged with Design (5048)">Design&nbsp;(5048)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/grid/" class="tag-size-2" title="View all images tagged with Grid (1498)">Grid&nbsp;(1498)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/homepage/" class="tag-size-1" title="View all images tagged with Homepage (1213)">Homepage&nbsp;(1213)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/icons/" class="tag-size-3" title="View all images tagged with Icons (1778)">Icons&nbsp;(1778)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/illustration/" class="tag-size-7" title="View all images tagged with Illustration (3211)">Illustration&nbsp;(3211)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/inspiration/" class="tag-size-20" title="View all images tagged with Inspiration (7817)">Inspiration&nbsp;(7817)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/interface/" class="tag-size-3" title="View all images tagged with Interface (1767)">Interface&nbsp;(1767)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/iphone/" class="tag-size-5" title="View all images tagged with iPhone (2486)">iPhone&nbsp;(2486)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/layout/" class="tag-size-3" title="View all images tagged with Layout (1762)">Layout&nbsp;(1762)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/light/" class="tag-size-4" title="View all images tagged with Light (2079)">Light&nbsp;(2079)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/logo/" class="tag-size-5" title="View all images tagged with Logo (2518)">Logo&nbsp;(2518)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/mac/" class="tag-size-4" title="View all images tagged with Mac (2240)">Mac&nbsp;(2240)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/navigation/" class="tag-size-1" title="View all images tagged with Navigation (1147)">Navigation&nbsp;(1147)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/photography/" class="tag-size-4" title="View all images tagged with Photography (2348)">Photography&nbsp;(2348)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/portfolio/" class="tag-size-10" title="View all images tagged with Portfolio (4159)">Portfolio&nbsp;(4159)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/poster/" class="tag-size-1" title="View all images tagged with Poster (1180)">Poster&nbsp;(1180)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/typography/" class="tag-size-10" title="View all images tagged with Typography (4363)">Typography&nbsp;(4363)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/web/" class="tag-size-14" title="View all images tagged with Web (5616)">Web&nbsp;(5616)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/web-design/" class="tag-size-3" title="View all images tagged with Web Design (1863)">Web&nbsp;Design&nbsp;(1863)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/webdesign/" class="tag-size-2" title="View all images tagged with Webdesign (1540)">Webdesign&nbsp;(1540)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/website/" class="tag-size-9" title="View all images tagged with Website (3817)">Website&nbsp;(3817)</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20110925202549/http://emberapp.com//explore/tags/white/" class="tag-size-5" title="View all images tagged with White (2520)">White&nbsp;(2520)</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a long way to go in order to accomplish this. 1. delete this question. 2. read [ask] (hint: you need to include actual JavaScript in your question). 3. Learn HTML, CSS, JavaScript. 4. Google "how to tag cloud js". Assuming that #3 will take some time, skip over to #4 (hint: refer to [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/create-a-tag-cloud-with-some-simple-css-and-even-simpler-javascript/)).

Comment: "_I suspect I will need some JS to find the most popular tag and normalize everything else from 0 to 1 using that?_": That's the general concept, yes. But the opacity minimum won't be 0 — rather the minimum value that represents the lowest contrast that you want for the least popular tags.

Comment: I realized that a bit after, makes sense @jsejcksn

Comment: @zer00ne I did my best. I summarized in the title, explained the problem first, and gave everything needed to reproduce. I googled of course too, but no one seems to have done exactly what I want, and my interpolation from another example like yours would be slower than just asking on SO

Comment: I'd like to step in here and offer you some accessibility advice before you proceed further: don't pursue this design if you care about the readability of your content: the visuals you've shown already fail contrast guidelines. See more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Understanding_WCAG/Perceivable/Color_contrast), [Accessible Web](https://accessibleweb.com/color-contrast-checker/), [WebAIM](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/)

Comment: Yeah, your effort is earnest which is why I haven't down voted or voted to close your question. Nevertheless, you need JavaScript in your question so we can fix your problem but your problem is not knowing JavaScript.

Comment: I figured out the logic portion, but using the specific framework I'm using, which is Hugo (Go instead of JavaScript)